# PHP 2d Array loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $item = "itemCount_".$row['id'];
    if ($_POST[$item] > 0)
    {
        $items2 = array( $i=> array($row['item'],$row['price']));
        $i++;
        echo $item." = ".$_POST[$item]." ".$i."<br>";
    }
}
```

I would have thought  that this would put each item in a array but it only puts the last item in the loop in. where is my fundamental flaw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$items2 = array( $i=> array($row['item'],$row['price']));
```

That just keeps reassigning `$items2` to a new array.  Don't even worry about the `$i` counter and use

```
$items2[] = array($row['item'], $row['price']);
```

[PHP Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing a new array every time you go through the loop, it's better to use the array_push() function.